# Using Xpath to select single node, when node contains namespace

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have following response for one of my SOAP request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <UploadIsoResponse xmlns="http://localhost:8000/gw/">
        <UploadIsoResult>false</UploadIsoResult> 
        <status>ISO File does not exist</status> 
        <md5>string</md5> 
        <days>9/18/2015 12:00:00 AM</days> 
        </UploadIsoResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I am using following code to parse it. However I am getting an error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**. This is actually because of the resulting null value returned from the xpath. Please help me on parsing single node.

```
public void fill_response_data(string xml_buffer)
{
    string TARGET_NAME_SPACE = "http://localhost:8000/gw/";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml_buffer);
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("msbld", TARGET_NAME_SPACE);
    XmlNode md5_node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:UploadIsoResponse/md5", ns);
    XmlNode md5_status_node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:UploadIsoResponse/status", ns);
    txt_md5_checksum.Text = md5_node.InnerText;
    txt_status.Text = md5_status_node.InnerText; 
}
```

`Exception :` System.Xml.XmlDocumentAn unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in IsoGateway.exe

Comment: I'd suggest using LINQ to XML rather than the `XmlDocument` DOM and XPath. It'd be much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding name space in xpath and below is the updated snippet.

```
  XmlNode md5_node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:UploadIsoResponse/msbld:md5", ns);
     XmlNode md5_status_node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:UploadIsoResponse/msbld:status", ns);
```